# How to print data from view fetch by cursor in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW pohled ("r_minimalni_doba_vysetreni", "r_id_pacienta", "r_id_doktora", "r_minimalni_doba_doktora") AS 
    SELECT MIN(v.DOBA_VYSETRENI), v.ID_PACIENTA, v.ID_DOKTORA, d.MIN_DOBA FROM vysetreni v, doktor d WHERE v.ID_DOKTORA = d.ID_DOKTORA GROUP BY v.ID_DOKTORA, v.ID_PACIENTA, d.MIN_DOBA;

DECLARE
     CURSOR  kurzor(vstup_id_pacienta IN NUMBER, vstup_id_doktora IN NUMBER) IS
        SELECT * FROM pohled WHERE "r_id_pacienta" = vstup_id_pacienta AND "r_id_doktora" = vstup_id_doktora;
     tmp pohled%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN kurzor(1, 1);
    LOOP
        FETCH kurzor INTO tmp;
        EXIT WHEN kurzor%NOTFOUND;
        dbms_output.put_line('How to print some data from tmp variable???');
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE kurzor;
END;
```

1) Create view
2) Create cursor 
3) Fetch view by cursor in loop..

So, all steps are OK, it working, but I dont know how to print some data from variable `tmp` - `tmp pohled%ROWTYPE;`.

When i run the code: `dbms_output.put_line(tmp.r_minimalni_doba_vysetreni);` I am getting error oracle - `PLS-00302: component must be declared.`

I dont know why?

Thank for your help.

EDIT:
Same problem for code:

```
DECLARE
     CURSOR  kurzor(vstup_id_pacienta IN NUMBER, vstup_id_doktora IN NUMBER) IS
        SELECT * FROM pohled WHERE "r_id_pacienta" = vstup_id_pacienta AND "r_id_doktora" = vstup_id_doktora; 
BEGIN 
    for tmp in kurzor(1, 1) 
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(tmp.r_minimalni_doba_vysetreni);
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle databases are, by default, case sensitive; however, they will also, by default, convert everything to upper-case so that the case sensitivity is abstracted from you, the user.

Unless you surround an identifier in double quotes, then the database will use whatever case you have used.

The best thing is to **NEVER** (unless you have an overriding business reason) use double quotes around identifiers and let Oracle manage the case:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW pohled (
  r_minimalni_doba_vysetreni,    -- Remove the double quotes here
  r_id_pacienta, 
  r_id_doktora,
  r_minimalni_doba_doktora
) AS 
  SELECT MIN(v.DOBA_VYSETRENI),
         v.ID_PACIENTA,
         v.ID_DOKTORA,
         d.MIN_DOBA
  FROM   vysetreni v
         INNER JOIN doktor d     -- Use an ANSI join rather than legacy Oracle join
         ON ( v.ID_DOKTORA = d.ID_DOKTORA )
  GROUP BY v.ID_DOKTORA, v.ID_PACIENTA, d.MIN_DOBA;

DECLARE
   CURSOR  kurzor(vstup_id_pacienta IN NUMBER, vstup_id_doktora IN NUMBER) IS
      SELECT *
      FROM   pohled
      WHERE  r_id_pacienta = vstup_id_pacienta -- Remove the double quotes here
      AND    r_id_doktora  = vstup_id_doktora;
   tmp pohled%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN kurzor(1, 1);
  LOOP
    FETCH kurzor INTO tmp;
    EXIT WHEN kurzor%NOTFOUND;
    dbms_output.put_line( tmp.r_minimalni_doba_vysetreni );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE kurzor;
END;
```

However, you could use your original code and surround the identifier in double quotes:

```
dbms_output.put_line(tmp."r_minimalni_doba_vysetreni");
```

Comment: Hello @MT0 thank you for your reply. Nice, now it working, thank you.